# Adding .js file to JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jsp

**I have my jsp page in WebContent/WebPages/WEB-INF and i want to access .js file in WebContent/js directory.** Before my .js file was in WEB-INF after reading so many posts on StackOverflow i moved it to WebContent/js directory. But then to am unable to access .js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/State.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="WebContent/js/State.js"></script>
```

I tried both but am unable to access .js file. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="js/State.js"></script>
<script  src="js/State.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank u @user3040563 but can u explain me how to write these paths its a bit confusing. Even i tried those which Arvind said.

Comment: Webcontent is your root path so you need to strt adding path from there.Since you have js after wecontent,u need to strt from der..Hope this helps u

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/State.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../js/State.js"></script>
```